# $('label').css('width') returns wrong values in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, width

On page load a Bootstrap's `navbar` is populated with labels up until no more fit in it. I'm doing this using their `width` property via `$('label').css('width')` and it's working fine in FF but when I test it in Chrome, the labels overflow the `navbar` and viewport.

Debugging the code I noticed the value returned by `$('label').css('width')` in Chrome is far from the same as stated in the browser's inspector tab, under **Computed**:

[image: CHROME]

and `console.log(parseFloat($('label').css('width')))` outputs: 64.725

On the other hand, in FF:

[image: FIREFOX]

and `console.log(parseFloat($('label').css('width')))` outputs: 82.4, which is right on cue.

**HTML**

```
<label class="btn btn-light" data-original-title="" title="">
    <a class="btn" href="http://localhost">
        <img src="images/amazon.png">&nbsp;TEXT
    </a>
</label>
```

My question is, how to obtain the actual width of the label in Chrome?

Thanx

**UPDATE**

Tried all of these

```
$('label')[0].clientWidth; //63
$('label').get(0).offsetWidth; //65
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle($('label')[0])['width']; //64.725px
$('label').css('width'); //64.725px
```

none of them even near the computed width in the image

**Temporary (hopefully) solution:**

*It was the image inside the label*

This was particularly weird and hard to find because, remember, it worked in a browser and not in another.

As it happens, I was querying for the width of the label before the image had been loaded into it, causing it to produce a misleading result.

I was using `$(window).ready()`, guilty as charged but, not `$(window).on("load", () => {})` nor `window.onload = () => {}` nor `window.addEventListener('load', () => {})` made it work, even though one of the key differences between the first and the rest is that `$(window).ready()` executes *as soon as the DOM is manipulable* and does not wait for images to load, while the rest waits for such images, although Chrome decided that's not a priority right now.

Guess who solved the problem: [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7VIpByhmU3U).

Quite a hack but, indeed, `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` was the hero this time, and yes, with a timeout of 0, nonetheless. Now the code actually waits for the images to load.

Note: I did switch to `window.onload = () => {}` as well, just in case.

I hope this saves someone else's time.

Comment: You should be able to use `$("label").width()`

Answer (score 0):

Try use getComputedStyle, but it just be read-only, could not set value for the DOM

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(DOM)['width'];
```

Comment: this returns exactly the same as `.css('width')`, see update